# Why is this expression returning NaN?

Tags: multiplicative-function

For smoother ship movement, I am going to gradually move it to it's actual location - So like this:

```
(mz - sz) / (10 * (60 / TerrainDemo.FPS))
```

mz is the ship's actual location on the Z axis - And I divide it by 10, and obviously at the end I account for the FPS.

However, on seemingly random occasions, this is returning NaN.

How can I fix this to not return NaN?

Comment: Make sure that you **avoid** the following combination of values: `TerrainDemo.FPS > 60 && mz == sz`. If `TerrainDemo.FPS` is a floating-point variable, then you might also need to make sure it is larger than 0.

Comment: What are, on these random occasions, the values of the variables?

Comment: @barakmanos Why would `TerrainDemo.FPS>60` be a problem? If `TerrainDemo.FPS = 120` and `mz = sz`, then `(mz - sz) / (10 * (60 / TerrainDemo.FPS)= (mz - sz) / (10 * (60 / 120)=(mz - sz) / (10 * (0.5)) = 0`, not `NaN`.

Comment: Most likely, `TerrainDemo.FPS` will sometimes be $0$. (Or `mz` or `sz` already `NaN`.)

Comment: @5xum: If `TerrainDemo.FPS` is an integer type, then `60/TerrainDemo.FPS` will be $0$, then `10*0` will also be $0$. Then, if one of `mz` or `sz` is a floating-point type, and `mz == sz`, you will get a floating-point division of $0$ by $0$, which will result with `NaN`.

Comment: If `TerrainDemo.FPS` is an integer type, then `(FPS > 60 || FPS < -60) && mz == sz` will yield `NaN`.If `TerrainDemo.FPS` is a floating-point type, then `(FPS == inf || FPS == -inf) && mz == sz` will yield `NaN`.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: This question is more suitable for Stack Overflow (where it will definitely be "on-topic"). Can you please tell me how to migrate it there, or perhaps do it yourself if I do not have high enough reputation for that? Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos That isn't logical. I was asking about why a mathematical expression was not valid. How is that a programming question?

Comment: @user2722083: `float`, `int` and `NaN` are purely programming terms (and most definitely **not** mathematical ones). So everything here **is** in fact pretty much programming-related, and I guess that this is why the question was closed as "off-topic". There is simply no such thing as `NaN` in mathematics. As you can imagine, being the one whose answer has been accepted (by you), I would be more than happy to keep it here. But a month after being closed, it will be removed completely. That is why I have suggested to migrate it to what appears a more appropriate place for it.

Comment: @barakmanos Oh okay. I actually didn't know that. Because I am home-educated, I learn almost all of my maths from programming techniques, which for obvious reasons regularly include things like "NaN", making me think that it was just another part of maths.

Comment: @user2722083: No, `NaN` is just some bit-sequence defined by the most widely-used floating-point standard (IEEE-754) for that purpose. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#NaNs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression gives `NaN` in each one of the following cases:

```
 mz type | sz type | FPS type | Condition
---------|---------|----------|-----------------------------------------
 int     | int     | float    | (FPS == inf || FPS == -inf) && mz == sz
---------|---------|----------|-----------------------------------------
 int     | float   | int      | (FPS  >  60 || FPS  <  -60) && mz == sz
---------|---------|----------|-----------------------------------------
 float   | int     | int      | (FPS  >  60 || FPS  <  -60) && mz == sz
```

In addition to that, if the value of any of these variables is `NaN` to begin with, then so will be the value of the entire expression.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has solved my issue.

Comment: @user2722083: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

In many scripting programming languages, when a variable or atrribute of object has not been declared, it is "undefined". So an arithmetic operation is NaN (Not a Number) when a variable is `undefined`, `null` or incompatible type with number operation.

So I think in some "moment" mz, sz or TerrainDemo.FPS cause a invalid operation.

The solution is find which variable is NaN and set a default value for this situation (maybe using conditionals or return 0 when your operation is NaN).

P.S.: Some language, like Javascript, have the special values NaN and Infinity. So

- Infinity +  -> Infinity
- Infinity - Infinity -> NaN
- Number / 0 -> Infinity (anothers raise an exception)
- Number / Infinity -> 0

To see all indeterminate forms go [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Comment: Java (which is what I am programming in) actually throws an Exception and crashes the program if I have not assigned a variable (or assigned a null variable) to something.